# Invalid cast from 'System.String' to 'System.TimeSpan' EF 4.1/MySql Connector/Net 6.4.4

Tags: c#, asp.net, mysql, entity-framework, entity-framework-4.1

For the life of me I cannot get this bug figured out - I have two time fields in mysql, properly mapping as Timestamp fields in ASP.net Entity Framework. I can assign and INSERT into the db no problem, however, whenever I try to load the data back out by simply querying the database I receive the following error message: ***Invalid cast from 'System.String' to 'System.TimeSpan'***

```
        using (hydraEntities db = new hydraEntities())
        {

            Employer = db.employers.Include("address").Where(em => em.EmployerId == EmployerId).First();
        }
```

I cannot figure it out, i've upgraded the mysql connector to the latest release praying that would solve the bug - however that did not fix it. Any help would be GREATLY appreciated!

Comment: Are you sure you want timespan? normally you would use dateTime.

Comment: Yea - a timespan is preferred as i'm only storing a time of the day and no specific date, the time could occur on multiple dates, for example, for a specific position an employee will work 8 to 5 , monday thru friday, so i only store the start time and end time

Comment: The TimeSpan class doesn't store the time of day. It represents the comparison between two dates. DateTime is likely what you are after.

Comment: In mysql its storing it as a time - however asp.net entity framework is representing it w/ a timespan

Comment: I've switched to datetimes - although its not the ideal situation it DOES work, so thanks for the comments guys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this.. TimeSpan is a deals with Length perhaps you meant TimeStamp.. 
what ever the case if you did mean TimeSpan.. can you double check and clarify..?

TimeSpan would work.. here is a something you could use.. problem is you will need to figure out the milliseconds of what's in the timespan field to replace your milliseconds with what I have pasted in this code example

```
DateTime dt = new DateTime().Add( TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds( 1304686771794 ) )
```

Comment: The problem is the code is auto generated by the Entity Framework - thus I really have no clue what to even supply in regards to code - I wish I could

Comment: Hi DJ - I've switched over to DateTime - although i wish timespan/time fields would have worked properly they didn't. Unfortunately as far as I know mysql timestamps and EF do not work - thanks for your help

Comment: It actually will work.. this boils down to a DataType conversion.. I hope that you will be able to fix the issue that you are having..

Answer (score 0):

Ok so this post is about how people have approached storing the time of day.
[C# DateTime: What "date" to use when i'm using just the "time"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/372601/c-sharp-datetime-what-date-to-use-when-im-using-just-the-time)

its not really something that C# understands as such so anything is a bit of a work around. If you really want a timespan you would probably be best to store that as an int in the database for the number of ticks in the timespan, then convert it in your model.

Another option would just to be to store the hours/minutes components in a data structure of your own.

eg

```
public class TimeOfDay
{
    public int Hours{get;set;}
    public int Minutes{get;set;}

    //possibly even
    public TimeSpan TimeSpan
    {
        get
        {
            return new TimeSpan(new DateTime(2000,1,1,Hours,Minutes,0).Ticks -new DateTime(2000,1,1).Ticks);
        }
    }
}
```